# Escape underline with the <a> tag for symbols

Tags: html, css

I am having a link, like the one below.

```
<a href="blah.com">Name <sup>&reg;</sup> title</a>
```

One the screen the ® symbol also has the underline in superscript, which does not look good. Can I remove the underline just for the ® symbol and still have the same 'a' tag around both name and title?

Comment: Do you mean that the underline appears above text baseline, or that it appears in the first place? Are you sure you want to have the “®” character superscripted? (In well-designed fonts, it is of superscript style as such.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the text decoration completely and place a border under it instead.

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

From a usability point of view, if you're going to place underlines under your links to denote them as links, the underline should be apparent under the entirety of the link. By removing the text decoration form the a element, declaring it as `inline-block` and placing a border under it, you achieve your desired results without the line floating under the ®. You can also spice up your links by changing the border to be `dotted` or `dashed`, or thickening/thinning on mouseover.

However, the most important part of this is **you do not add extraneous markup for stylistic reasons**.

Fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/gs5jC/

Comment: Thanks Mike. Its perfectly fine with me to have a gap. Still the js fiddle has underline even the other option you have given me. another thing I have noticed is that, the underline is also in superscript in chrome but not in firefox.

Comment: This means *replacing* underline by a bottom border. While a border might be more suitable, the question asks about removing underline for one character, so whatever the merits of the suggestion might be, it is not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: "One(sic) the screen the ® symbol also has the underline in superscript, which does not look good." He is concerned about *presentation*, so this method **does** answer the question. Likely, he was unaware there was another way to solve the issue other than just removing the underline under the symbol, which breaks the continuity of the hyperlink presentation, and is why he asked the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no, at least not with your current markup (see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LEg9s/)). This is per the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-line-property):

> ### 2.1. Text Decoration Lines: the ‘text-decoration-line’ property
>
> ...
>
> Specifies what line decorations, if any, are added to the element. Values have the following meanings:
>
> **‘none’**: Neither produces **nor inhibits** text decoration.
>
> ...

However, you can change your markup a bit to support this ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/LEg9s/1/)):

```html
<a href="#"><span>Foo</span> <sup>&reg</sup></a>
```

```css
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a span {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: I think you have it the opposite way around...You also probably want something like `font-size: 0.75em` for the superscript.

Comment: No, I don't. You can't remove `text-decoration` from children elements.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I figured it wasn't you. Just in case the person that did comes back around :)

Comment: Thanks. In that case the below one works well for me. <a href="#"><span>Foo</span><sup>&reg;</sup> <span>blah<span></a>

Comment: If this answered your question, be sure to mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to it (below votes). Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen It's bad practice, yes, but so is styling an underline with `border`. It's one of those exceptions to work around a *limitation* in CSS, just like using extra `<div>`s in order to be able to set up a layout correctly. Not ideal by any means, but sometimes necessary.

Comment: It's not a limitation of CSS. Both `text-decoration` and `border` are *styles*, not content. `border` applies the line to the block element in the box model while `text-decoration` applies the line to the inline element of the text. When trying to accomplish stylistic changes, you should always do it in CSS first. If it cannot be accomplished in CSS, that is the only time you fallback to markup. Since this can be accomplished in CSS without extraneous markup, this answer is less than ideal.